# create a parent node of a specific existing node using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have another problem i need to

create a parent node of a specific existing node using c# linq

here is the input

```
<tag>
    <New>some content</New>
    <b> bold </b>
    <New> content two </New>
    <p> p tag </p>
</tag>
```

here is the output

```
<tag>
    <newtag><New>some content</New></newtag>
    <b> bold </b>
    <newtag><New> content two </New></newtag>
    <p> p tag </p>
</tag>
```

this is my code

```
XElement addtag = XElement.Parse(rTxtoutput.Text);
            IEnumerable<XElement> add =
                from el in addtag.Descendants("New").ToList()
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in add)
            {

            }
```

Comment: 1) store the parent of `el`, 2) create the `<newtag>` node and set it as parent of `el`, 3) set the parent of `<newtag>` to the previous parent of `el` which has been retrieved in 1

Comment: thanks @Philippe for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

solution: thanks @philippe for the idea.

```
const string xml = @"<tag>
        <New>some content</New>
        <b> bold </b>
        <New> content two </New>
        <p> p tag </p>
    </tag>";

                XElement addtag = XElement.Parse(xml);
                IEnumerable<XElement> add =
                    from el in addtag.Descendants("New").ToList()
                    select el;
                foreach (XElement el in add)
                {
                    el.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("p", el));
                    el.Remove();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(addtag.ToString());
```